# Restkit how to make a syncronous handshake protocol

Tags: ios, restkit

I have to implement interaction with a Web Service.
One of its method can be described as follows:

1) The client makes a POST to the server

2) The server sends back an answer

3) The client sends an ack back to the server

This interaction must be repeated `k` times.
My attempt:

```
for (NSDictionary* event in arrayOfEvents)
    {
    // Preparo l'oggetto richiesta
    SynchObj* reqObj = [[SynchObj alloc] init];
    [self generateRequestData:reqObj e:event];

    if (<some-error-happned>)
    {
        [objectManager removeRequestDescriptor:syncRequestDescriptor];
        [objectManager  removeResponseDescriptor:syncResponseDescriptor];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"syncDone"
                                                            object:nil];
        // Reset
        [self resetStatus];
        return;
    }
    [objectManager postObject:reqObj
                         path:@"sync.json"
                   parameters:nil
                      success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                      // Shall I start a new request here?
                        [operation waitUntilFinished];
}
```

As I wrote into the code, shall I start the new request inside the success code and 3rd one inside the success block of the second one?
I think this is a problem of synchronous post, isnt'it? 
If somebody can advice I will appreciate.

Comment: Notifications? What for? How would you use them? How do they help over code in completion blocks?

Comment: I have to wai the answer from the server before sending the message in 3).

Comment: I am not asking to find a tool, library or resource. I am asking if my solution is good, correct.

Comment: It would still seem that you can just add your code to the success completion blocks to make the next request. I don't see notifications adding any value for you.

Comment: Could you please make an answer with a sample code?I was thinking to use synchronous requests...

Comment: Why? What is it that you don't understand about the success completion block and what you can do with it? You need to edit the question with some code to show what you have tried.